# Straight and Binary insertion sort

Tags: c++, sorting, data-structures, binary-search

Hello I was asked to improve insertion sort by using binary search instead of linear. The problem is that the best case is now O(n log n) instead of O(n) due to **data comparisons**, which made the program if not slower in some cases equal. Here is my binary insertion sort code:

```
void InsertionSort(int data[], int size)
{
    int index = -1;
    for(int i = 1,temp,j;i<size;i++)
    {
        temp = data[i];//DM O(N)
        int high = i,low = 0,mid;//DM O(N)
        while(low <= high)//DC O(nlogn)
        {
            mid = (low + high) /2;
            if(temp < data[mid])
            {
                high = mid - 1;
                index = mid;
            }

            else if (temp > data[mid])
            {
                low = mid + 1;      
            }

            else if(data[mid] == temp)
            {
                index = mid;
                break; 
            } 

        }
        for(j = i;j > index;j--)
        {
            data[j] = data[j-1];//DC Worst Case O(n*n) but the exact is summation of n(n+1) / 2 nad best case o(1)
        }
        data[j] = temp;//DM O(n)
    }   
}
```

Comment: But it's improved the worst case, right?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth No it is still O(n * n) since it will make n(n + 1) / 2 shifts

Comment: Indeed, this won't affect the asymptotic complexity, but it might improve the runtime in practice.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth in the worst case it almost produced the same time but instead of 0 ms while sorting 100000 numbers it got 16 it should be faster not slower or equal since logically binary search is much faster than linear

Comment: You might see a larger speedup when sorting a type with _expensive comparisons_ since that is what the binary search reduces. Try it on something other than plain old `int`.

Comment: @Blastfurnace thank you yes it did from 5000 to 3000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start your binary search with a biased stage that favours the best case. Instead of going directly to `(low+high)/2`, start at position `i-1`, then `i-2`, then `i-4`, `i-8`, `i-16`, `i-32`... until you find a smaller element, or until `i-whatever` gets lower than `low`. Then continue with the ordinary binary search.

Note that this optimisation comes at a cost. The best case ---sorted or almost sorted data--- takes O(N) time, but the average case and the worst case get a bit slower with respect to the simple binary search version.

```
void InsertionSort (int data[], int size)
{
    int i, j, high, low, mid, hop;
    int temp;

    for (i=1; i<size; i++)
    {
        temp = data[i];

        high = i;
        low = 0;
        hop = 1;

        do
        {
            mid = high - hop;
            hop <<= 1;

            if (temp < data[mid])
                high = mid;
            else
                low = mid + 1;
        }
        while (low+hop <= high);

        while (low != high)
        {
            mid = (low + high) / 2;

            if (temp < data[mid])
                high = mid;
            else
                low = mid + 1;
        }

        for(j=i; j>low; j--)
            data[j] = data[j-1];

        data[j] = temp;
    }   
}
```

Note also that `high` is assigned `mid` and not `mid+1`. The case where `temp==data[mid]` is treated exactly as the case where `temp>data[mid]`. This is to keep a good property of insertion sort: it is a [stable sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability). It makes no difference when sorting plain integers, though.

Comment: i did not understand this part                                                        do
        {
            mid = high - hop;
            hop += 1;

            if (temp < data[mid])
                high = mid;
            else
                low = mid + 1;
        }
        while (low+hop <= high);

Comment: @user1948105: It is not hop+=1, but hop<<=1, which is the same as hop*=2, or hop=hop*2. The hop starts at 1 and is multiplied by 2 each time. Thus, mid starts at high-1 and then it get further by an increasing speed: high-2, high-4, high-8, ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of a binary insertion sort compared with an ordinary insertion sort. My benchmark times are conclusive. The binary version is way faster.

```
#include <iostream>

#define NB_VALUE 1000
#define VALUE_RANGE 200

class Profiler
{
    
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> initTime;
    const char *m_name;
    public:
    Profiler(const char *name = nullptr): initTime(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()), m_name(name){}
    ~Profiler()
    {
        if(m_name)
             std::cout << m_name << " ";
        auto begin = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(initTime).time_since_epoch();
        auto now = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()).time_since_epoch();
        
        auto duration = now - begin;
        double millisecond = duration.count() * 0.001;
        std::cout << millisecond << " ms\n";
    }
};

template <class T>
void swap(T &t1, T &t2)
{
    T tmp = t1;
    t1 = t2;
    t2 = tmp;
}

template<class T>
int binaryFindIndexOfSmallestBiggerOrEqual(T array[], unsigned int begin, unsigned int end, T value)
{
      int delta = end - begin;
      if(delta < 0)
           return -1;
    
    if(delta == 0)
    {
          if(array[end] > value)
                return end;
             else
                return -1;
    }
    
    int midIndex = begin + delta / 2;
    
    if(  array[midIndex] < value )
    {
           return binaryFindIndexOfSmallestBiggerOrEqual(array, midIndex+1, end, value);
    }
    else
    {
        if(midIndex == 0 || array[midIndex -1] <= value)
            return midIndex;
        else
            return binaryFindIndexOfSmallestBiggerOrEqual(array, begin, midIndex - 1, value);
    }   
}

template <class T>
void binaryInsertionSort(T array[], unsigned int begin, unsigned int end)
{
    if(end <= begin)
        return;
        
    int sortedUpTo = begin;
    int insertionIndex;
    while(sortedUpTo < end)
    {
        if(array[sortedUpTo] < array[sortedUpTo + 1])
            insertionIndex = -1; 
        else
             insertionIndex = binaryFindIndexOfSmallestBiggerOrEqual(array, begin, sortedUpTo, array[sortedUpTo + 1]);

        if(insertionIndex != -1)
        {
            T tmp = array[sortedUpTo + 1];
            memmove(array + (insertionIndex + 1), array + (insertionIndex), sizeof(T)*(sortedUpTo - insertionIndex + 1));
            array[insertionIndex] = tmp;
        }
        ++sortedUpTo;
    }
}   

template <class T>
void insertionSort(T array[], unsigned int begin, unsigned int end)
{
    for (int i = begin + 1; i <= end; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i; j > begin + 1; --j)
        {
            if (array[j - 1] > array[j])
                swap(array[j - 1], array[j]);
            else
                break;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
     int arrayToSort[NB_VALUE];
    
//******** RANDOM CASE *********
    for (int i = 0; i < NB_VALUE; ++i)
      arrayToSort[i] = rand() % (VALUE_RANGE + 1) * 2 - VALUE_RANGE;
    
    Profiler *p = new Profiler();
    binaryInsertionSort(arrayToSort, 0, NB_VALUE - 1);
    delete p;
    //Timer : 0.119ms
    
    for (int i = 0; i < NB_VALUE; ++i)
    arrayToSort[i] = rand() % (VALUE_RANGE + 1) * 2 - VALUE_RANGE;
    
    p = new Profiler();
    insertionSort(arrayToSort, 0, NB_VALUE - 1);
    delete p;
    //Timer : 1 989ms
    
//********* ALREADY SORTED CASE ************
   for (int i = 0; i < NB_VALUE; ++i)
    arrayToSort[i] = i;
    
    p = new Profiler();
    binaryInsertionSort(arrayToSort, 0, NB_VALUE - 1);
    delete p;
    //Timer : 0.003ms
  
    for (int i = 0; i < NB_VALUE; ++i)
    arrayToSort[i] = i;
    
    p = new Profiler();
    insertionSort(arrayToSort, 0, NB_VALUE - 1);
    delete p;
    //Timer : 0.004ms
    
//********* REVERSED ORDER CASE ************
   for (int i = 0; i < NB_VALUE; ++i)
    arrayToSort[i] = NB_VALUE - 1;
    
    p = new Profiler();
    binaryInsertionSort(arrayToSort, 0, NB_VALUE - 1);
    delete p;
    //Timer : 0.046ms
  
    for (int i = 0; i < NB_VALUE; ++i)
    arrayToSort[i] = NB_VALUE - i;
    
    p = new Profiler();
    insertionSort(arrayToSort, 0, NB_VALUE - 1);
    delete p;
    //Timer : 3 878ms
    
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also replace the last else :`else if(data[mid] == temp)` with simple `else`
because it obvious that is is true if the former two were not true...

Comment: It will make no difference